# JIRA dialog workflow is not translated

Tags: jira

My German translations are used everywhere except the dialog workflow overview.

If I click on the following. Which by the way is shown in German:

[image]

Only the English versions shows up. Even if the user and the system language is German:

[image]

What can I do?

**Edit 1**: This is also the case for action buttons, as here:

[image]

Comment: You can update your Jira installation. If the problem persists, file a bug report.

Comment: I have version  6.3.12 you think this is nessesary?

Comment: I think this might be a bug in Jira. Sometimes such bugs are already fixed in the newest version. 6.3.15 is the latest release. File a bug at the vendor of Jira. That's it what you can do about it. Or you try fixing it yourself, search for the strings and try to replace them. I wouldn't do the latter.

Comment: Do you know for sure that this feature is included normally?

Comment: No, I don't know. But you expect it to be translated. It is not translated. It is a (missing translation) bug. If it is translated, the bug will be closed as invalid.

Comment: what does this has to do with `stackoverflow`?

Comment: I asked because I thought someone knows how to configure it. Now I know it is not possible .. so this could also be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a standard feature in Jira. You'll need to go through the language pack and translate the transitions.